# Why can't IIS log in to SQL using machine name

Tags: iis, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5, integrated-security

I've looked at dozens of stackoverflow articles, web articles and nothing offers a solution.

My website requires Integrated Security.  It uses a SqlFileStream and as I understand only works if integrated security is enabled.  My entire website runs when configured as sql authentication except for this feature when configured (properly) but the option to turn it off is a performance hit so I'd like to go the route of making it work rather than disabling it.

SQL and IIS are currently running on the same box.

My connection string:

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=db;Connection Lifetime=8;Pooling=true;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

I have configured my website to use Network Service in the app pool.  I have created an account for my computer name: domain/computername$

I have created a user in my database mapped to the login for the computername account.

I have followed multiple sets of instructions to the letter and none solve this issue.

When using integrated I ALWAYS get:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'domain\computer$'.
```

I have only one connection string so I'm not accidentally changing it.

I am running on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and SQL Server 2012 SP2.

I am developing in Visual Studio 2013 on .NET 4.5

The server is on a domain and all the account names match including the account name that is being reported as login failure.

What am I doing wrong or is there some sort of special instructions when IIS and SQL are the same box?

Comment: What is the *state* in SQL Server's error log? "Login failed" could be any of about 50 different things. Find the state in the error log, then check [this list](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/01/14/sql-server-v-next-denali-additional-states-for-error-18456.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  State 11. States 11 & 12 mean that SQL Server was able to authenticate you, but weren't able to validate with the underlying Windows permissions. It could be that the Windows login has no profile or that permissions could not be checked due to UAC. Try running SSMS as administrator and/or disabling UAC. Another reason could be that the domain controller could not be reached. You may need to resort to re-creating the login (see this post from Simon Sabin).  I have since disabled UAC and ran the SQL script in the link it provides.  No luck.